# How to shortern || code in if statement c++

Tags: c++

Basically doing a password generator. want to filter out ASCII chars 91-96
here is my if statement. How can i shortern it to make it like 
"randomnumber == 91-96" without having to repeat myself?

```
if (randomnum == 91 || randomnum == 92 || randomnum == 93 || randomnum == 94 || randomnum == 95 || randomnum == 96) // We dont want values 91 - 96
    { // Do nothing
    }
```

Comment: `if(randumnum >= 91 && randomnum <= 96)`

Comment: Like cool guy said, by taking a step back, and abstracting the condition, followed by expressing it in terms of C. If you want the number to be larger then "a" **and** smaller than "b", you write just that.

Comment: @IVIaximumPower Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you found an answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the check mark under it's score. This helps keep the focus on unresolved questions.

Comment: @AlexMeuer Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to filter out ASCII chars between 91 and 96, you can do it the following way too:

```
if (randomnum >= 91 && randomnum <= 96)
{ 
     // do stuff
}
```

This shortens the code considerably. The && works to check whether the char is less than or equal to 96 **AND** greater than or equal to 91. This is called the logical AND operator.

EDIT: following @PeteBecker's advice, here is a better way of doing the if-statement:

```
if (randomnum >= '[' && randomnum <= '`') // Notice that I use a char value here with the comparison operator
{ 
     // do stuff
}
```

The difference here is that `randomnum` is a char variable, therefore it makes sense for us to only use char values in our comparison. Using an int value, like in the one above will also filter out a non-ASCII values as pure integers. While both forms of if-statements may work, it would be better practice to user char values in comparison operators with char variables.

Also, I found the '[' and '`' from the ASCII table; its what DEC value 91 and 96 respectively refer to.

Comment: Note that this will also filter out **non**-ASCII characters between 91 and 96. It operates on **values**, regardless of their origin. ASCII is a convention for mapping values and displayed characters. It is not a fundamental property of integer values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @PeteBecker, I updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter out the parts between `'Z'` and `'a'`,

```
if (randomnum > 'Z' && randomnum < 'a')
```

would be more readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (randomnum > 90 && randomnum < 97) // We dont want values 91 - 96
{ // Do nothing
}
```